# Something wrong with my rig. All scrunched up and missing faces?

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging

I tried to copy and paste an armature onto a saved model in an alternate .blend file, but my model became all messed up: faces missing and what not.

Here's the photo of what it looks like.
[image]

It also says *Auto-run disabled*. I'm not sure what that has to do with the rig itself, but I thought I'd add it.

Comment: Was your rig in multiple parts when you copied it? Perhaps it was in say 3 parts, and you only copied one.

Comment: I only copied the bone rig, the model, and that air tank behind him counts as its own separate object. I copied the entire model all together, the tank does't have any rigs so it doesn't have any problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Rigify, the addon uses some drivers to control the bones, and drivers use Python expressions to work. Auto run of Python scripts are disabled by default for security reasons, but you can allow blender to auto run scripts by changing your user preferences. To do this press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, then head over to *File* and enable Auto Run Python Scripts:

[image]